# Can't write human readable words to file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, encoding

I am trying to build a list of all words appearing in files in a specified directory, and then save this list to a file. When I try to print out any of the list's positions it appears to be ok (it is human readable), but after I write it to a file I see only byte-numbers. Here is my code:

```
import os

directoryList = ['/Users/Kuba/Desktop/Articles/1', '/Users/Kuba/Desktop/Articles/2', '/Users/Kuba/Desktop/Articles/4']
bigBagOfWords = []

for directory in directoryList:
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        currentFile = open(filename, 'rt', encoding = 'latin-1')
        for line in currentFile:
            currentLine = line.split(' ')
            for word in currentLine:
                if word.lower() not in bigBagOfWords:
                    bigBagOfWords.append(word.lower())
        currentFile.close()

saveFile = open('dictionary.txt', 'wt', encoding = 'latin-1')
for word in bigBagOfWords:
    saveFile.write(word)
    saveFile.write('\n')
saveFile.close()
```

File "dictionary.txt" contains lines like this below:

> 0000 0007 0078 0064 
>   006b 002e 0074 0078  0074 696c 6f63 626c  6f62 0000 0010 0000 00ec
>   0000 09e8 ffff ffff ffff 0000 0000

How do I force python to write those words in human - readable encoding? Am I doing something significantly wrong here?

Comment: Are you certain your *input* articles don't contain those lines?

Comment: How did you view `dictionary.txt` in the first place? Are those hex codes the *literal* text; e.g. there are 7 0x30 ASCII codepoints at the start (7 `'0'` characters), followed by 0x37, another 2 0x30, etc.? Or are you looking at this in a hex editor and bytes are displayed as hexadecimal representations and you have 3 NULL bytes (0x00) followed by a 0x07 character, another null, then a `'d'`, etc.?

Comment: I am sure input articles contain only human-readable normal English words. I open the output file "dictionary.txt" in sublime, and the output is just as I've shown above. What is more, before I started iterating over multiple directories the output file was fine.

Comment: That means SublimeText determined it was a binary file and shows you the hex contents. It does the same for other binary file formats; try to open a `.pyc` file for example. Sounds like at least one file in you directories is not a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've opened a [`.DS_Store` OS X desktop information file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) and added it to your output file. When you opened the file in Sublime Text the text editor shows you binary files in a columned hex dump format.

The character sequence `locblob` is a characteristic of the proprietary format. You also have the text `xdk.txt` in UTF-16 hidden in the hex dump you showed us; the `.DS_Store` file stores icon positions and other attributes for files on non-native OS X filesystems.

Filter these files out when you are looping over directories. Typically, you want to ignore files starting with `.`:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename[0] == '.':
        continue  # skip hidden files
    filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

Comment: So, it explains it all: before I was iterating through directories (and so: giving a direct path to a single file) it was working because it did not try and read '.' starting files. Including an "if" as proposed above fixed it.